# PDF creation using wkhtmltopdf in share hosting with php code

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Unable to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf in shared hosting with PHP code

in my shared hosting not able to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf

by using ssh client I can create pdf, the command i used in ssh is

```
"./wkhtmltopdf-amd64-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 www.google.co.in test.pdf"
```

this working

in my PHP code, I used as

```
exec("./wkhtmltopdf-amd64-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 www.google.co.in test.pdf");
```

it is not working

I tried `exec("./public_html/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 www.google.co.in test.pdf");` and by removing ./ also,
not working

Comment: Hi, try using a library wrapper for wkhtml2pdf: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf it will make your life easyer and also will give you any system related errors it encounters

Comment: can we use all the features available on wkhtmltopdf in this library ? and how can we use that like page numbering,header etc

Comment: This library is just a wrapper, it is still using wkhtml2pdf under the hood and you can pass in all the values you pass to wkhtml2pdf via command line. You will simply have a nice OO interface(do not confuse fir UI) to wkhtml2pdf and error reporting without trying to catch output from exec manually